# Epic Online Services - Service Metrics

Tags: epic-online-services

Today I wanted to check what type of live errors our development deployment produced in the past 30 days. However, no matter what, the Live failed API calls are always showing the following error.

`Oops. Looks like we don't have data to display yet.`
[image]

Should I have to setup first something, because Lobbies and other metrics are updating correctly.
I found no documentation about this section of the developer portal so if someone has experience with this please help me out.

I'm using the C# SDK 1.14.2